# Why is %f working incorrectly for large double numbers in print statement?

Tags: c, gcc

```
double a = 1E100
printf("%f", a);
```

It seems to be printing a different value other than 1 followed by a 100 zeros:

```
10000000000000000159028911097599180468360808563945281389781327557747838772170381060813469985856815104
```

What might be the problem here?

Comment: `1E100` cannot be represented exactly in the bits of a double. Consequently, printing it yields something close to, but not exactly the same as `1E100`.

Comment: So what is the maximum degree of precision for a double number?

Comment: A double can store up to about 17 decimal digits.  After that, the values become meaningless.

Comment: See [Why Powers of Ten Up to 10²² Are Exact As Doubles](https://www.exploringbinary.com/why-powers-of-ten-up-to-10-to-the-22-are-exact-as-doubles/). Powers larger than that can't be represented exactly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `double` type, assuming it uses IEEE 754 double precision floating point representation, only holds about 16 decimal digits of precision.

So any decimal digits after that will only be an approximate value, i.e. the closest value to `1E100` that it *can* represent.